# How do I deserialize a derived class with json.net

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I'm currently getting back the following json from a service that I do not own:

```
{
    "auc" : 320658953,
    "item" : 31294,
    "owner" : "Amacid",
    "ownerRealm" : "EarthenRing",
    "bid" : 289493,
    "buyout" : 371150,
    "quantity" : 1,
    "timeLeft" : "LONG",
    "rand" : 0,
    "seed" : 0,
    "context" : 0
}, {
    "auc" : 321175921,
    "item" : 82800,
    "owner" : "Drakonys",
    "ownerRealm" : "EarthenRing",
    "bid" : 7000384,
    "buyout" : 7507980,
    "quantity" : 1,
    "timeLeft" : "VERY_LONG",
    "rand" : 0,
    "seed" : 161297536,
    "context" : 0,
    "petSpeciesId" : 293,
    "petBreedId" : 9,
    "petLevel" : 1,
    "petQualityId" : 3
},
```

And I'm trying to deserialize it into proper CLR objects. It's obvious that these object hold a an object hierarchy on the server side; something like `Item` and `PetItem : Item` where `PetItem` has the extra 4 properties at the end there.

How do I handle this? I'm using Json.net to deserialize most of the other results from other services that are more consistent, but I'm looking for a strategy to handle situations like this. I've seen some solutions on how to have Json.net deserialize everything into an implied base class, but I'm not sure how to handle this upcasting type scenario

Comment: do you have some code already?

Comment: I suppose it's possible, although it grates at my psyche to think that an "item" could have a bunch of properties that may or may not be used or mean anything.

Comment: If you have the possibility of massaging the incoming data, you could add "$type": "Namespace.ItemType" type name hinting, then build your classes to match.

Comment: Another option is a single Item class with all the common properties, and then load any remaining attributes into a Dictionary<string,object>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is yours example: http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.ru/2012/02/json-deserialization-with-jsonnet-class.html?m=1

You just have to use overloaded method

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>
  (r.EventArgs.Result, params Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter[] converters)
```

And write your converters

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any alternative besides creating the class hierarchy in c# and then have some sort factory that checks for the presence of signature keys on the json side, creating the right c# object. `petSpeciesId` is probably a good candidate for distinguishing between `Item` and `PetItem`.

Ask yourself whether you really need to do this.  Maybe a sparse class with unused properties will suit your purposes. Or just use `System.Json.JsonObject` to get an unordered key/value collection.

@Evgeny 's link to the blog post is a correct approach, but it does seem like an incredible amount of work! There's probably a simpler variation, but at bottom that's the work that needs to be done.

Comment: Indeed that does seem like an amazing amount of work. I'm going to probably do what you suggested and just make a big bucket type object in the meanwhile, but @Evgeny technically answered the actual question so I should select that answer. But you have my upvote for sanity, sir